# Get the last echo statement inside a function and put inside variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script, inside that statement, it has several commands with few echo commands. Is it possible to get the only last echo statement as return statement and ignore all other echo commands?

```
#!/bin/bash

function statement(){

echo "This is the first statement"
echo "This is the second statement"
# do something else
echo "The result is ok"  # I want to display only this in my output.
}


last_echo=$(echo $(statement))

echo "${last_echo}"
```

This will output every statement:

```
This is the first statement This is the second statement The result is ok
```

Expected output:

```
The result is ok
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `tail` to extract just the last line.

```
result=$(statement | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: Wow .. thanks I didn't realize the power of `tail` command

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin `readarray` command:

```sh
readarray -t lines < <(statement)
last_line="${lines[-1]}"
```